# AS3 - Flex - StageWebView on ios shows html5 video as fullscreen by default?

Tags: ios, html, actionscript-3, video, apache-flex

When showing a HTML5 `<video>` tag in a `StageWebView`, **on iOS devices only**, the video shows up as **full screen** by default.

Here is the `<video>` tag I am using:

```
<video id="vid" controls autoplay webkit-playsinline="true" playsinline="true">
```

Adding `webkit-playsinline` and `playsinline` does solve the problem when browsing with the device's browser, but does not solve the problem in when showing the page in my app's `StageWebView`.

How can I solve this issues?

Comment: Did you try to use StageWebView with native option `new StageWebView(true)` ?

Comment: @OlegKnaus Yes I tried that.